# How to import a file of classes in a Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: class, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a file that contains classes. Example :

---

```
abstract class TestBase
{
    String name
    abstract def fTest()

    def bobby(){
        return "bobby"
    }
}
class Test extends TestBase
{
    def fTest(){
        return "hello"
    }
}
class Test2 extends TestBase
{
    def fTest(){
        return "allo"
    }
    def func(){
        return "test :)"
    }
}
```

I want to import the file in my Jenkins pipeline script, so I can create an object of one of my class. For example :

---

```
def vTest = new Test()
echo vTest.fTest()
def vTest2 = new Test2()
echo vTest2.func()
```

---

How can I import my file in my Jenkins Pipeline ? Thx.

Comment: because of the `echo` command i assume you are in jenkins-pipeline and not just groovy. could you please update your question and tag if it's so.

Comment: I updated it ! Thx :)

Comment: Related https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31155

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like this:

**Classes.groovy**

```js
class A{
    def greet(name){ return "greet from A: $name!" }
}

class B{
    def greet(name){ return "greet from B: $name!" }
}

// this method just to have nice access to create class by name
Object getProperty(String name){
    return this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(name).newInstance();
} 

return this
```

pipeline:

```js
node{
    def cl = load 'Classes.groovy'
    def a = cl.A
    echo a.greet("world A")
    def b = cl.B
    echo b.greet("world B")
}
```

Comment: It gives me the error : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: A for class...

Comment: try `def a = cl.getProperty('A')` instead of `def a = cl.A`

Comment: that's a question to your jenkins administrator.

Comment: Scripts not permitted to use method java.lang.Class getClassLoader. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.  -  how solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276341/jenkins-ci-pipeline-scripts-not-permitted-to-use-method-groovy-lang-groovyobject

Comment: I get the same error as @Emile. I feel like there's got to be a way to access the class from loaded groovy without jumping through hoops. Accessing functions from loaded groovy is easy and works as expected.