# loading groovy class in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am currently trying to load a custom groovy class from a file in my jenkins pipeline. I have attempted the solution proposed here:

[How to import a file of classes in a Jenkins Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811293/how-to-import-a-file-of-classes-in-a-jenkins-pipeline)

as...

> JenkinsPipelineUtilityClass.groovy

```
class JenkinsPipelineUtilityClass {
    final String name = "TEST"
    protected void printName() {
        println this.name
    }
}
Object getProperty(String name){
    return this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(name).newInstance();
}
return this
```

> Jenkinsfile

```
def classes = load "myPath/JenkinsPipelineUtilityClass.groovy"
```

and also attempted using the  GroovyClassLoader as so (using the above class again)

> Jenkinsfile

```
def parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
def loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent)
def groovyClass = loader.parseClass(readFile("myPath/JenkinsPipelineUtilityClass.groovy")).newInstance()
```

and I run into the same error with both:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException call org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.produce_error(WorkflowScript:22)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:139)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor541.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:103)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor541.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:60)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor541.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've checked the in-process script approval and nothing is in there and I'm stumped.

Comment: usually this exception provides a method name. please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: Have you tried with `pipeline{}` inside the groovy file.

Comment: ok I've edited it with the full error trace @daggett

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi we're not using declarative pipelines, and ideally I'd like to do this without using them.

Answer (score 0):

whenever i get a "RejectedAccessException" i immediately check the "In Process Script Approval" screen,

this screen allow the Jenkins administrator to decide which methods / classes the script writer is allowed to run/access,

this screen can be found at the url:

```
http://JENKINS_SERVER:JENKINS_PORT/scriptApproval
```

for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/scriptApproval
```

or you can access it through the administrator menu option:

Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins ->  In-process Script Approval

[image: in process script approval menu]

you can read more about it in [jenkins docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/)

so you just need to go to that screen and press approve button on the class/method that was denied,