# Jenkins log4j vulnerability testing from pipeline job

Tags: java, security, jenkins, log4j

I am trying to make sure my Jenkins instance is not exploitable with the latest log4j exploit.

I have a pipeline script that runs, I tried following this instruction :

https://community.jenkins.io/t/apache-log4j-2-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228/990

This is one of my stages of my pipeline script:

```
stage('Building image aaa') {
      steps{
        script {
          sh "echo executing"
          org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup.class.protectionDomain.codeSource
          sh "docker build --build-arg SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT=staging -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG ."
        }
      }
    }
```

But I get a different error than what's described here and I'm unsure if I'm checking this correctly.  This is the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:31)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
....etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way to check if you Jenkins has the log4j vulnerability (through plugins or otherwise).

1. Go to https://your-jenkins.domain/script
2. Paste `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup.class.protectionDomain.codeSource`

If the output is `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class: Script1` You're good then, otherwise you're not good.

This way you don't have to change your pipeline to test or go through the approval process like mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490162/169277), you can just paste and verify without needing to configure additionally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a class name would be directly interpreted as a groovy codeSource argument in a declarative pipeline (as opposed to a scripted one)

Try the approach of "[How to import a file of classes in a Jenkins Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44828343/6309)", with:

```json
node{
    def cl = load 'Classes.groovy'
    def a = cl.getProperty("org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup").protectionDomain.codeSource
    ...
}
```

Note that `getCLassLoader()` is by default disallowed, and should require from an [Jenkins administrator In-process Script Approval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412951/6309).

Comment: thanks! Now I get a different issue (No such property: org for class: WorkflowScript)

Comment: @Remember_me Probably a missing quotes issue. I have edited the answer accordingly.